# how to find the number of metrics and types of metrics used in microstrategy project

Tags: microstrategy

I am new into microstrategy an trying to find out the specific metrics(different metrics for different vendors) used in a project and trying to pull the total number of metrics in every group/vendor. How can we do this using the command manager scripts like : LIST ALL METRICS IN FOLDER FOR PROJECT.
Using this command I get multiple like 50k + metrics and my system freezes out. So need help with correct script or some solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try search support in rest API. You can add metric as the query parameter and use page by to query object list.

https://www2.microstrategy.com/producthelp/Current/RESTSDK/Content/topics/REST_API/REST_API_Workflow_Searching.htm